# How to use angular value in freemarker macro?

Tags: angularjs, freemarker

I am trying to access a value set as an angular property to be accessible in a freemarker macro.

`<#macro macroName fieldValue> ... </macro>`

In the FTL,

`<@macroName fieldValue={{valueFromAngular}}>`

This does not renders and gives a 'Template inclusion failed' error while rendering.

I looked for a solution on SO, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Angular values are resolved after FreeMarker templates, as FreeMarker only runs on the server side. So, FreeMarker just sees `<@macroName fieldValue={{valueFromAngular}}>` as is, which is not valid.

Maybe `<@macroName fieldValue='{{valueFromAngular}}'>` will work, but that depends on what the macro does (if it just prints `fieldValue`), and if template output is parsed by Angular.